# Jinja variables within the Flask url_for function

Tags: flask, jinja2

I have tried multiple different things, but cannot get the URL to appear as /item like I want it to. I know that everything else is functioning correctly because if I simply replace {{item}} with a string, it works fine. Am I missing something here?

Here is the code section where the problem lies:

```
<div class="person_images_group">
    {% for item in names %}
        <div class="personlist">
            <a href={{ url_for('name', name = {{item}} ) }}>
                <img id={{ item }} src="" alt={{ item }} width="40" height="40">
            </a>
        </div>
        <script>
            document.getElementById("{{ item }}").src = getName("{{ item }}");
        </script>
    {% endfor %}
<div>
```

Thank you

Answer (score 31, accepted):

You try use `{{}}` in `{{}}` block. So right usage is `{{ url_for('name', name=item) }}`.

Comment: Thank you! I could have sworn that I tried this. Must have had something else incorrect at the time. Muchas gracias!