# javascript document.write image error

Tags: javascript, html, flask, document.write

I am using Flask and pass variables (image_name) to javascript to get dynamic web content.
I use those variables within document.write() to display a image file.
Depending on the variable image_name the required .jpg file should be loaded.

This is my JS code:

```
document.write('<img class="img-circle profile_img" '
+ 'src="{{ url_for(' + "'static', filename='images/"
+ "'{{ image_name }}'" + ".jpg' )}}"
+ '" onerror="'
+ "this.onerror=null;this.src='../static/images/"
+ "'{{ image_name }}'"
+ ".jpg';"+'"'+"/>");
```

With image_name="max_mustermann" I want the output to be:

```
<img class="img-circle profile_img" src="{{ url_for('static', filename='images/max_mustermann.jpg' )}}" onerror="this.onerror=null;this.src='../static/images/max_mustermann.jpg';"/>
```

When I run Flask and try to load the page, my broswer is showing the following error.

> jinja2.exceptions.TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ',', got
>   'static'

Comment: Can you elaborate what exactly you want to achieve? Whatever you are doing, this is not the right approach.

Comment: There is at least a problem with quotes: You are putting the image_name in single quotes.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Jinja variables within the Flask url\_for function](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23988561/jinja-variables-within-the-flask-url-for-function)

Comment: Thanks!  The problem was that I used   {{}} within {{}}.