# TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ',', got 'static'

Tags: python, flask, jinja2

I am getting following error in given code

**TemplateSyntaxError: expected token ',', got 'static'**

code:

```
<img src="{{ url_for('static',filename='foods/paneerparatha.jpg') }}" alt="Paneer Paratha">
```

Answer (score 3):

Your code seems to be correct, but you might have `{{}}` inside another `{{}}` which would cause your error message.

Reference: This might be a duplicate of the following, unanswered question: [ [javascript document.write image error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42553950/javascript-document-write-image-error) ]
 where that seemed to be the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Another way such an error could creep into your code(happened to me) is when you have a comment inside the template that has an unclosed {{}}, but flask also reads that line.
This was the comment that was causing the error in myu case.

```
<!-- {{ url_for('static', filename='./assets/ -->
```