# Flask jinjas with url_for and anchor

Tags: python, html, flask, jinja2

I have a table, where I would like the row (or each td) to link to the url_for another page with the anchor `tb[1]`

```
...

{% for tb in TB %}
<tr>
    <td><a href="{{ url_for('gl', _anchor={{ tb[1] }} ) }}">{{ tb[0] }}</a></td>
    <td><a href="{{ url_for('gl', _anchor={{ tb[1] }} ) }}">{{ tb[1] }}</a></td>
</tr>
{% endfor %}
...
```

This isn’t working as there are `{{ }}` within `{{ }}`

Thanks

Comment: Remove the `{{` and `}}` as that section is already in the Python code.  Specifically `url_for('gl', _anchor=tb[1])`

Comment: Actually this should be the correct duplicate [Jinja variables within the Flask url_for function](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23988561/jinja-variables-within-the-flask-url-for-function)